# jQuery pagination in cakephp1.3

Tags: cakephp-1.3

By using below code , everytime page refresh when i click on next.
what I want =>  everytime page should not refresh, only div is updated.

this is my view

```
       <script type="text/javascript"> 

      $(document).ready(function() { 
        loadPiece("<?php echo $html->url(array('controller'=>'daily_videos','action'=>'pagination_viewall'));?>","#container-box"); 

        var href = <?php echo $html->url(array('controller'=>'daily_videos','action'=>'pagination_viewall'));?>;
        var divName = "container-box";
        var divPaginationLinks = "container-box #pagination a";

             $(divPaginationLinks).click(function() { 
                var thisHref = $(this).attr("href"); 
                // loadPiece(thisHref,divName);

                 $("#container-box").load(thisHref);
                return false;
             });

       }); 
</script> 

   <div id="container-box" class="clearfix">
   </div>
```

Below my controller

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler'); 
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Javascript');
var $paginate = array('limit'=>'8');
function pagination_viewall()
{
    $this->layout = NULL;
    $arrdailyvideos = $this->paginate();        
    $this->set('arrdailyvideos', $arrdailyvideos);
     if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {  
        $this->render("viewall");
        return;  
    } 

}
```

If You have any link for this que,post here

Answer (score 0):

I would help you but are you debugging your JS code? It seems to full of errors (no loadPiece function, url strings without "", etc..)

I think the proper way to do this would be something like te following:

```
$().ready(function() {
  $('#container-box #pagination a').live('click', function(e){
    // Add a class loading to the container box
    $('#container-box').addClass('loading');

    // Get the data from the link into the container box
    $('#container-box').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
      // Remove the loading class again
      $(this).removeClass('loading');
    });

    // Stop the default action, following this link
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```